# How to have a single "HelperClass.IsLoggedIn()" method for the entire ASP.NET web project?

Tags: asp.net

This is a common need I have on every page:

```
if (session["LoggedIn"] == null || ((bool)session["LoggedIn"] != true))
....//user is not logged in. return.
```

I was wondering, is there a way I can create a class "Helper" with a method signature `bool IsLoggedIn()` and call that method from a page so that automatically it can check if the page it was called from has the `session["LoggedIn"]` set to `true`? Something like this:

```
class Helper
{
  public bool IsLoggedIn()
  {
    System.Web.UI.Page page = ***FindCallerPageSomeHow***();
    if(page.session["LoggedIn"] == null || ((bool)page.session["LoggedIn"] != true))
      return false;
    return ((bool)page.HpptContext.Session["LoggedIn"] == true);
  }
}
```

Ofcourse, I could try implementing an interface for each codebehind class, but thats repetitive. Also, I could pass in the `HttpContext` for `IsLoggedIn`, but that's a bit of clutter..

Any ideas? Is there a simple-to-implement pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always have a static class in a library somewhere, but my favorite technique is simply to create your own Page class and add properties or override events there.

```
public class myPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public void myPage()
    {
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn()
    {
        System.Web.UI.Page page = ***FindCallerPageSomeHow***();
        if(page.session["LoggedIn"] == null || ((bool)page.session["LoggedIn"] != true))
            return false;
        return ((bool)page.HpptContext.Session["LoggedIn"] == true);
    }
}
```

Then in the code behind of your actual page, you would have

```
public partial myAspxPage : myNamespace.myPage
{

}
```

As an example, my page class usually contains a public property called ValidUser that contains pertinent user information (so I don't have to keep looking it up). If that value is null, then I don't have one. If it's not, then I have what I need. Then whenever I create a new page in my site, I just have it inherit my page class instead of the default.

EDIT: Added your method in for a little more clarity.

Comment: Yeah, but then I have to remember to derive from myPage..no biggie, but is there a better way? But certainly this sounds nice.. since I can then make every page inherit..

Comment: This is the most extensible way I've ever seen. I'll be looking in the answers to see if someone comes up with something more thorough.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this approach I would probably add a extension method on the session. But using [formsauthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) is usually a lot easier.

**Update**

Btw, here is the extension method:

```
public static bool IsSignedIn(this HttpSessionState session) {
    //Use the session to check if the user is signed in
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if(Page.Session.IsSignedIn()) {
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the code in the master page?  That way any pages that need to be tested for the user being logged in can inherit from that master page and all is handled automatically.   Otherwise, you're just repeating yourself in the code for every page.

Comment: I could, but then I have more than one master page, and so that's repeated code too..

Comment: But master pages can inherit master pages...  so you have a base master page that contains most of your default styling, then one that inherits from it that requires user logged in and one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a base class called BasePage which would inherit from System.Web.UI.Page. I would then have the codebehind class inherit from BasePage.

In BasePage, you just add a method called IsLoggedIn(), and you can call it from anywhere within your code behind class.